# Is unique_ptr<Derived> to unique_ptr<Base> up-casting automatic?

Tags: c++11, polymorphism, c++14, unique-ptr

I know it is possible that a derived class `unique_ptr` can take place where base class `unique_ptr` is required for polymorphic types. For example, while returning from function

```
unique_ptr<Base> someFunction()
{
     return make_unique<Derived>(new Derived());
}
```

or passing to function as argument.

```
// Function taking unique pointer
void someOtherFunction(unique_ptr<Base>&& ptr)
// Code calling this function
someOtherFunction(std::move(ptrToDerived));
```

My question is: Is this upcasting always automatic? Or do we need to explicitly perform it using `dynamic_cast`?

Comment: It seems automatic conversion is working for you so far. Why do you think you might need anything else? If you suspect you might need something else, why not check the documentation?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Do you mean to say at run-time? Cause it compiles on VS2015

Comment: Sorry misread it, but the rest still applies.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi [you broke C++](http://cpp.sh/6to64).

Comment: @HumamHelfawi I also tried it on g++ 4.9.2 and it's working. To be specific `someFunction` is a pure virtual function declared in base class and I'm using exactly this line in all its derived classes
`return make_unique<Derived>(*this)`

Comment: @n.m. I did actually :$ sorry

Comment: @ChadwickRobbert forget about my comments.. sorry

Comment: @n.m. So as both the compilers are not cribbing and not giving any warnings should I assume that automatic conversion works perfectly fine? Actually I would appreciate someone giving me exact reason (may be a specific clause in standard) why it works. That's why I'm waiting

Comment: @HumamHelfawi it's ok :)

Comment: Yes, it's designed to work just like with regular built-in pointers, and it does work just like with built-in pointers. Pointer-to-derived automatically converts to pointer-to-base.

Comment: It works because ´..._ptr<A>` has a templatized constructor that accepts a `..._ptr<B>`, and it works precisely when `B*` is convertible to `A*`.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks a lot. Would you mind writing it as an answer? So that I can mark it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The (draft) standard says:

```
// 20.8.1.2.1, constructors
...
template <class U, class E>
  unique_ptr(unique_ptr<U, E>&& u) noexcept;
template <class U>
  unique_ptr(auto_ptr<U>&& u) noexcept;
```

Those are constructors from *any* unique_ptr. The standard further restricts their usage by clauses like this:

> 24 *Remarks*: This constructor shall not participate in overload resolution unless `U*` is implicitly convertible to `T*` and `D` is the same type as `default_delete<T>`

The effect of this remark is that `unique_ptr<T>` is constructible from `unique_ptr<U>` precisely `U*` is convertible to `T*` (and all deleter requirements are met). In particular, when `T` is an unambiguous public base class of `U`.

Since the constructor is not `explicit`, it serves as an implicit converter from `unique_ptr<U>` to `unique_ptr<T>`.

Comment: can you provide a source for where you cite from?