# Compiler error when passing unique_ptr<Derived> to function that accepts unique_ptr<Base> parameter

Tags: c++, android-studio

I have the following code:

```
class A {

};

class B : public A {

};

class C {
    void func(std::unique_ptr<A> &&p) {

    }
    void init() {
        std::unique_ptr<B> b(new B);
        func(std::move(b));
    }
};
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36401999/is-unique-ptrderived-to-unique-ptrbase-up-casting-automatic), the above code should work fine. Apparently, unique_ptr was designed to be able to mimic the polymorphism of built-in pointers. Compiler errors **don't appear** on VS2015, but **do appear** in Android Studio.

The IntelliJ error reads: "Parameter type mismatch: Class 'std::unique_ptr is not compatible with class 'std::unique_ptr'"
When I try to build, the compiler error reads: "error: no viable conversion from 'unique_ptr' to 'unique_ptr'".

The following flag is set in my Cmake file (building a native library in Android Studio):

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")
```

Android Studio is using **GNU 4.9.**

I should note that the up-casting works fine when done at initialization (i.e. std::unique_ptr a(new B);), but for some reason it doesn't work when trying to pass as a parameter (as seems acceptable based on the above-listed link).

I know I can probably work around this, but I don't want to sacrifice the clarity and safety of my code because the compiler is being hinky. Up until now, the majority of STL has worked fine in Android Studio, but I may just have to build the library independently in VS if I want to use this functionality.

**Edit:** In case it's unclear, my question specifically is: Why am I getting this error in one IDE, but not in the other? Is there some way for me to make it work in the former (so I can continue to code in that environment)?

**Edit 2:** When I try to do the exact same thing with *shared_ptr*(for both passed derived and expected base parameters), no error displays. Weird.

Comment: And the error you are getting is..?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Works as expected. [LiveDemo](http://ideone.com/GbSq1W)

Comment: @mkaes, the fact it works for gcc on ideone is irrelevant to the question about **Android Studio**

Comment: @StoryTeller, yup did not read this far.

Comment: What version of g++ is Android Studio using?  What version of glibc?

Comment: @MartinBonner, edited. GNU 4.9

Comment: I also get this error in CLion 2018.2.2, while the code compiles fine with GCC 7.2.0. I suspect it is a bug in the IntelliJ typechecker, rather than GCC.